Error when connecting to Amazon RDS using pymysql: Database connection failed Cannot set verify_mode to CERT_NONE when check_hostname is enabled
I am trying to connect to Amazon RDS using mySQL but I am getting an error message for pymysql connect. The code I have used is:
 conn = pymysql.connect(auth_plugin_map={'mysql_clear_password': None}, host=ENDPOINT, user=USER, password=token,
                           port=PORT, database=DBNAME, ssl_ca='certbundle.pem', ssl_verify_identity=True)

The certbunble.pem was downloaded from the Amazon RDS website.
I have set the host, user, password, port and database values to the same as those in the database.
I have used the recommended code from Amazon as being this with the values changed. Details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Python.html
The full code is shown below. I have updated the variables.
import pymysql
import sys
import boto3
import os

ENDPOINT="mysqldb.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
PORT="3306"
USER="jane_doe"
REGION="us-east-1"
DBNAME="mydb"
os.environ['LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN'] = '1'

#gets the credentials from .aws/credentials
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
client = session.client('rds')

token = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname=ENDPOINT, Port=PORT, DBUsername=USER, Region=REGION)

try:
    conn =  pymysql.connect(auth_plugin_map={'mysql_clear_password':None},host=ENDPOINT, user=USER, password=token, port=PORT, database=DBNAME, ssl_ca='SSLCERTIFICATE', ssl_verify_identity=True)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT now()""")
    query_results = cur.fetchall()
    print(query_results)
except Exception as e:
    print("Database connection failed due to {}".format(e))          
                

I have tried removing the ssl_ca bundle but this did not work.

Do you use the correct full path of certbunble.pem?

Try adding ssl_verify_cert=True after ssl_verify_identity=True
